# DateTimePickerでユーザーに月までしか選択させない

Tags: c#

ご質問させていただきます｡

DateTimePickerでユーザーに年月までしか選択させたくないです｡
以下の画像のように月をクリックすると､その月のカレンダーが表示されてしまいますが､
そうではなく､datetimepickerのvalueを2016/02/01で入れて､入力を終了させたいのです｡

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ちなみにDateTimePickerのテキストはFormatでyyyy/mmとする事で年月までしか表示させないようにする事はできました｡
DateTimePickerで上記のような制御は可能でしょうか｡

もしくは､他の良い方法がございましたら､ご教授ください｡
よろしくお願いします｡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DropDownイベントに以下を実装します。

```
// pinvoke:
private const int DTM_GETMONTHCAL = 0x1000 + 8;
private const int MCM_SETCURRENTVIEW = 0x1000 + 32;

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);

private void dateTimePicker1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTimePicker myDt = (DateTimePicker)sender;

    IntPtr cal = SendMessage(dateTimePicker1.Handle, DTM_GETMONTHCAL, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    SendMessage(cal, MCM_SETCURRENTVIEW, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)1);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

表示に関しては`Format`プロパティを`Custom`にし、`CustomFormat`プロパティに`yyyy年 MM月`などの書式を設定すればよいと思います。

この状態でも`Value`には年月以外の値も含まれている場合がありますが、これに関してはイベントか派生クラスで値を丸めるしかないです。基本的には`new DateTime(year, month, 1)`のような処理を変更時や値の取得時に行えばよいです。

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var v = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    dateTimePicker1.Value = new DateTime(v.Year, v.Month, 1);
}
```

なお上の方法ではすべてのコントロールにイベントを設定する必要がありますが、もっと本質的に対処したい場合は`DateTimePicker`の派生型を実装してください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。 user13314さんの回答が近いですが、pgrhoさんも貴重なお時間での解答ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2):

Pao@Office の 村井です。
私も入用だったので、こんな感じで作ってみました。荒いですが、わかりやすいかと
は思います。
ご参考まで。

```
    bool flgカレンダー = false;
    int yyyy = 0;
    DateTimePicker dt_;
    private void dt_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt_ = (DateTimePicker)sender;
        tmカレンダー.Enabled = true;
        flgカレンダー = true;
        yyyy = ((DateTime)dt_.Value).Year;
    }

    private void dt_CloseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmカレンダー.Enabled = false;
        flgカレンダー = false;

    }
    private void tmカレンダー_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmカレンダー.Enabled = false;

        dt_.Select();
        SendKeys.SendWait("^{UP}"); // Ctrl↑キー送信


    }
    private void dt_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt_ = (DateTimePicker)sender;
        if (flgカレンダー)
        {
            if (yyyy != ((DateTime)dt_.Value).Year)
            {
                yyyy = ((DateTime)dt_.Value).Year;
            }
            else
            {
                dt_.Select();
                SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}"); // Enterキー送信
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846455/how-can-i-set-the-datetimepicker-dropdown-to-show-months-only
↑こちらと同様な質問かと思ったのですが、違いましたでしょうか。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014280/how-can-i-programmatically-close-the-dropdown-calendar-of-a-datetimepicker-or-up
↑値が変更されたタイミングでドロップダウンを閉じるには、ShowUpDownプロパティで対応すればよさそうです。

ただしドロップダウンの初期表示時や、値が変更されない場合の対応も含めて、
日のカレンダーを表示しないようにする方法はわかりませんでした。
（Windows Formsの場合）

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。同じ質問です。(私の場合はyearlyとmonthlyですが)内容をもう少し確認し、実装チャレンジしてみます。　結果をこちらに書き込ませていただきます。