# MonthCalendarを年、月の表示のみで日を非表示にしたい

Tags: c#

WindowsFormアプリケーションのMonthCalendarの初期表示を
下図のように月表示にし、月を選択しても日のカレンダーを表示しないようにしたいと考えています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

XAMLのCalendar.DisplayModeを「CalendarMode.Year」にしたような表示をイメージしています。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @kunif それはWPFの記事であり、質問のWindowsFormとは無関係です。

Comment: こちらはWinFormsでの方法しょうか？ [DateTimePickerでユーザーに月までしか選択させない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/21731/26370)

Comment: 回答いただきありがとうございます。datePickerのようにクリック時にカレンダーが表示されるのではなく、最初からカレンダーが表示されているMonthCalendarの形を考えています。

Comment: 使い方での工夫ではなく、同等＋αのものを作られているようです。[MonthCalendar Calendar - Control](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24450/MonthCalendar-Calendar-Control)